# Unable to changePage to an externally loaded page in JQM with PhoneGap

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am having issues loading an external HTML JQM fragment when the application runs in phonegap. The Loading screen shows up briefly but nothing else happens.

I have narrowed down a problem to very simple code which I put on github, https://github.com/edasque/simple_page_load_test .

The public Android application sits at https://build.phonegap.com/apps/58244 .

This will work as a JQM application in a browser (even an Android browser) and does work without issue in the android emulator but I can't get it working on an actual device.

The Button works but not the footer button which does a changePage to an external URL. $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages is set to true and so is $.mobile.pushStateEnabled. I am using Phonegap 1.3, jQuery Mobile 1.0 & jQuery 1.6.4.

I have tested this on an HTC Sensation. This works in the Android SDK Emulator (2.1). Nothing appears in the logcat other than my debug code.

Answer (score 2):

had a similar problem..
Look at my code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
$.support.cors = true;
$.mobile.pushStateEnabled=false;
});
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>
```

Links are defined as

```
<a href="http://website-returning-jqm-pages" data-role="button" data-icon="info" data-iconpos="left">Info</a>
```

I believe that pushStateEnabled must be false for it to work, because I had a similar issue with the above code. It worked on simulator, but not on device. PhoneGap:build debug showed response in DOM, but it was not seen on the mobile phone.

Hope it helps..